# Fibonacci series and RecursionError using dict.get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I use the following code to calculate an element of the Fibonacci series.
The code works correctly as is

```
def fib(n, lookup=dict()):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        lookup[n] = n

    # This works
    if n not in lookup:

    # However, this doesn't
    # if not lookup.get(n):

        lookup[n] = fib(n - 1, lookup) + fib(n - 2, lookup)

    return lookup[n]

print(fib(6))
```

Now, if I use

`if not lookup.get(n):`

instead of:

`if n not in lookup:`

I get a RecursionError, even though I am only calculating the 6th element!:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Why does this error appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lookup.get(0) -> 0
0 in lookup -> True
```

0 is a "falsey" value, and you recurse when you get a falsey value, so the version with `get` is causing you to recurse infinitely when you hit zero (to infinite negative values since you don't have a check on that).

Comment: The solution is to use `if lookup.get(n) is not None` since that's what a missed get returns by default

Comment: The more Pythonic solution IMO is to use `if n not in lookup`.  Why obfuscate?  :)

Comment: or `if lookup.get(n) is None` in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @SamStafford I agree, I just wanted to know why I was getting a different outcome using .get

Comment: This kind of bug is basically the reason that relying on "truthiness" of non-bool types is generally discouraged in Python style guidelines.  I.e. don't use something else as a proxy for `in`, and don't use a truthy check as proxy for `is not None`.  :)